# isNumber method accepts letter D

Tags: java

My method checks a user input if it is an integer. If it is, it prints a certain something in my code, if it is not an integer, it prints Invalid input. It works good except for when i input any integer ending with the letter "d", it accepts it as an integer. How do I fix this? Here's my code so far.

```
static boolean isNumber(String text) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(text);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Input is non-numerical or incorrect.");
        return false;
    }
}

do {
     System.out.print("Input loan principal amount : ");
     input = s.nextLine();
} while (!isNumber(input));
     double loan = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Comment: why you parse double when you need an integer? do `Integer.parseInt()` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2), floating point types can have suffixes (shortent version):

```
FloatingPointLiteral:
    DecimalFloatingPointLiteral
    HexadecimalFloatingPointLiteral

DecimalFloatingPointLiteral:
    Digits . Digitsopt ExponentPartopt FloatTypeSuffixopt
    . Digits ExponentPartopt FloatTypeSuffixopt
    Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffixopt
    Digits ExponentPartopt FloatTypeSuffix

...

FloatTypeSuffix: one of
    f F d D
```

If you already using [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), you can use `nextDouble()` or `nextBigDecimal()` (which is better if your program is going to deal with money  values like in your case).

Comment: It would be better to point to the documentation of [`Double.parseDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))/[`Double.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) as that is the formal definition of its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a typical homework question for beginners.

Your teacher does not want you to find shortcuts and use existing functions that will give you the answer in one line, but to create a loop and check every character in the string one by one.

Like this:

```
for (char c : text.getChars()) {
    //code that checks if c is a digit character and exits if it is not
}

return true;
```

Remember that trying to use existing functions like `parseDouble` or `parseInt` will fail for very long numbers that should still be valid!